# Pods cannot resolve kubernetes DNS

Tags: kubernetes, dns, coredns, flannel, kube-proxy

**TL;DR**

From a pod I am able to resolve DNS addresses only when I am using CoreDNS endpoint IP. How to make pods use coreDNS IP address?

**CoreDNS configuration**

- IP address: 10.96.0.10
- endpoint: 10.244.0.222

**Kubelet configuration**

```
...
clusterDNS:
  - 10.96.0.10
...
```

**Flannel**

Default configuration from: https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel

**Cluster**

Is up and running and have these pods:

- coredns
- etcd
- apiserver
- controller-manager
- flannel
- scheduler

Also, the cluster consists of only a single master node (that is schedulable).

**Pod setup**

```
# run pod
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never --image=infoblox/dnstools:latest dnstools
```

**Test cases**

```
# 1
nslookup kubernetes.default
# output: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

```
# 2
nslookup kubernetes.default 10.96.0.10
# output: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

```
# 3
nslookup kubernetes.default 10.244.0.222
# output: resolved address, Address: 10.96.0.1
```

```
# 4
ping 10.96.0.1
# output: all packages lost
```

```
# 5
ping 10.96.0.10
# output: all packages lost
```

```
# 6
ping 10.244.0.222
# output: all packages received
```

**How have that happened?**

That issue appeared when I was updating a cluster. I have reinstalled kube-flannel and coreDNS services with their default equivalents:

- https://github.com/coredns/helm#configuration
- https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel

Throughout this process I have also uninstalled kube-proxy.

I don't know if kube-proxy is a necessary component of a k8s or does a flannel can be an alternative but I tried to reinstall it with this command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71519601/19570235 However, without any luck.

```
# Error message:
could not fetch a Kubernetes version from the internet: unable to get URL "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt":
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing clusterDNS section in kubelet from `10.96.0.10` to `10.244.0.222`.

After that I have restarted kubelet service (k8s is working on Ubuntu) and pods. Now pods can resolve hostnames and other services, like google.com.

I am not really sure if that is a workaround or if it is necessary to provide coreDNS endpoint to the kubelet config and because of that I will keep this post open for a while before accepting this answer.